# How do I create multiple class instances in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, animation, automation

I'd like to create a potentially unlimited amount of instances of a certain class within my javascript document:

```
let trees;
const treespawn = () => {
  let x = random(50, windowWidth - 50);
  let y = random(windowHeight /22, windowHeight / 1.13);
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    trees[i] = new Trees(x, y);
    return trees[i];
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0, 111, 10);
  trees.trunk();
  trees.leaves();
  trees.shudder();
}

class Trees {
  constructor(x, y) {
    stuff--stuff--stuff
  }
  trunk() {
    stuff--stuff--stuff
  }
  leaves() {
    stuff--stuff--stuff
  }
  shudder() { 
    stuff--stuff--stuff
  }
}
```

Some points:

- the trees variable is declared globally because I can't think of a way to keep my class function calls in scope.
- I'm using p5 hence the function draw. I've created all my other classes in the setup() function.

Basic explanation:

I'd like to create my Trees class object many times and have them appear on my canvas at the start of each level of the game I'm making. This would require around 20 trees per level inside the parameters set to let x and let y. In higher levels of my game I may want to increase the amount of trees.

You can see how simply writing out 20-30 variable declarations, creating those classes and calling all of the functions inside each class would be impractical.

I realise this must be done with some sort of array methodology. 
Can anyone help me here?

Thanks in advance!

Update:

This is as far as I've gotten and no console error message but I see no trees on the canvas.

```
function draw() {
  background(0, 111, 10);

  () => {
    let x = random(50, windowWidth - 50);
    let y = random(windowHeight /22, windowHeight / 1.13);
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      trees[i] = new Trees(x, y);
      trees[i].trunk();
      trees[i].leaves();
      trees[i].shudder();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `let trees = []` <- initialize it to an array, then it should work?

Comment: Ahh good point I can play around with that BUT if I do that to my trees declaration all of my class function calls are broken.

Comment: I don't get you. For sure `trees.trunk()` doesnt work as `trees` is an array. You might want `for(const tree of trees) tree.trunk()` and so on.

Comment: With p5, if I call a class function outside of function draw() it will not display on the canvas. Also, trees = new Trees(x, y) has to be inside a non-looping function like setup() I believe.

Comment: Then call it inside `draw()` maybe?! Also the second statement makes little sense, you are probably missinterpreting your result as `return trees[i]` ends your loop after the first iteration.

Comment: Check out my question edit. Thoughts?

Comment: What is `() => {  /*...*/ };` intended to do? If the answer is "I don't know" just remove it maybe ...

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

`random` is not a native Javascript function, so if you're not getting it from a library or from elsewhere, you might need to define it:

```
function random(lowerBound, upperBound) {
    var range = upperBound - lowerBound + 1;
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * range);
}
```

---

Try this:

```
class Trees {
  constructor() {
    stuff--stuff--stuff
  }
  trunk() {
    stuff--stuff--stuff
  }
  leaves() {
    stuff--stuff--stuff
  }
  shudder() { 
    stuff--stuff--stuff
  }
}

const treespawn = () => {
  let x = random(50, windowWidth - 50);
  let y = random(windowHeight /22, windowHeight / 1.13);
  return new Trees(x, y);
}

let trees = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  trees.push(treespawn());
}

function draw() {
  background(0, 111, 10);
  trees.forEach(tree => {
    tree.trunk();
    tree.leaves();
    tree.shudder();
  });
}
```

Comment: `Try this` is not an answer. What have you changed?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This looks like it could work. Tried some combinations but I'm now getting Uncaught ReferenceError: random is not defined and a the function calls in my draw function are not defined. Can't figure out what it could be! @JonasWilms if you look at the code he's changed quite a lot...

Comment: You might need to define the `random` function as I have above.

I'm not sure about the draw function problem. Where does your code call the draw function? Perhaps you could set up a codepen at https://codepen.io/ so we could help you debug further?